# spring validation framework

Tags: spring

is it possible to use spring validation framework with restful service.?if it so how can we do that

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can - you can build restful services with spring-mvc, and you have the validation mechanism available there.

Comment: thanks for your response.how to use @resource annotation for reading the property files

Comment: @rajan - that seems like a completely unrelated question? If so, ask another question. If not - please clarify how it relates to this one.